# Can't install php5.6

Tags: php, php-5.6

I had some problems with php so I decided to remove it and install it again. This is how I removed it:

```
sudo apt-get purge php.*
```

But maybe this was somehow wrong because now I can't install something different than php7. This is how I try to do it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'php5.6-json' for regex 'php5.6'
Note, selecting 'php5.6-common' for regex 'php5.6'
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 98 not upgraded.
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? I've been trying to solve it for the last couple of hours but my head will explode soon. 
**By the way I'm running on a 16.04 Ubuntu**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried other ways to purge php5 as mentioned in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59886/how-to-completely-remove-php)?

```
sudo apt-get -y purge libapache2-mod-php5 libapache2-mod-php5filter libexpect-php5 libgv-php5 libow-php5 php5 php5-adodb php5-auth-pam php5-cgi php5-cli php5-common php5-curl php5-dbg php5-enchant php5-exactimage php5-ffmpeg php5-fpm php5-geoip php5-gmp php5-idn php5-imagick php5-imap php5-interbase php5-intl php5-json php5-lasso php5-ldap php5-librdf php5-mapscript php5-memcache php5-memcached php5-mhash php5-midgard2 php5-ming php5-mssql php5-mysql php5-mysqlnd php5-odbc php5-pgsql php5-ps php5-pspell php5-radius php5-recode php5-remctl php5-rrd php5-sasl php5-snmp php5-sqlite php5-suhosin php5-svn php5-sybase php5-tidy php5-tokyo-tyrant php5-uuid php5-xcache php5-xdebug php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl
```

Also, in that thread **bento** mentioned that 
`sudo apt-get purge php.*` command can have side effects.

Comment: Yes, I saw that thread and now I'm afraid that some important packages have been removed and I don't know how to restore them.